# Configure Rebus routing (endpoint) in code and not in app.config

Tags: rebus

I would like to use #rebus in OneWayClientMode and at the same time configure the endpoint addresses in code and not via app.config.

Is this possible? I can find no trace of it in the fluent configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have two options: 1) route messages explicitly when you send them, and 2) implement your own routing logic using `IDetermineMessageOwnership´

The first option is pretty easy, and it is pretty explicit - you can simply go `bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(destination, message)` whenever you send a message. You should of course take care to not hardcode the destination too many times which could lead to problems later on :)

The second options is also easy, but it is slightly more implicit - you can implement the [`IDetermineMessageOwnership`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/IDetermineMessageOwnership) interface which is basically a way to map a message type to an endpoint, and then make Rebus use it like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .MessageOwnership(m => m.Use(myImplementation))
    .(...)
```

Unless I was going to do only one or two `bus.Send`s, I would go for the latter option :) happy routing!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to give a more explicit example of option 2, because I had to search through the examples to find out how to type in "myImplementation", and it is really quite simple. Suppose you want a queue identified by sWorkerId to receive all messages, this is what you do:

```cs
    Configure.With(...
                 .MessageOwnership(o => o.Use(new RebusConfig(sWorkerId))) 
                 .CreateBus()
                 .Start(RebusConfig.NumberOfWorkers)
```

RebusConfig implements IDetermineMessageOwnership as:

```cs
public class RebusConfig : IDetermineMessageOwnership
{
  private string m_sWorkerRoleEndpoint;

  public RebusConfig(string sWorkerRoleEndpointId)
  {
    m_sWorkerRoleEndpoint = sWorkerRoleEndpointId;
  }

  public string GetEndpointFor(Type messageType)
  {
    return m_sWorkerRoleEndpoint;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps ...